# Capture USB mouse raw data using libusb

Tags: c#, usb, hid, libusb, libusbdotnet

I want to capture raw data from a USB mouse using **libusb** library by [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29).

I can read data with the **UsbEndpointReader** class, but there is a problem.

When I try to read data it seems that Windows tries to read too, and I can't read all data and the OS can't either, because mouse movements have some steps. I want to read all data and let the OS read those data too (I mean without problem in moving the cursor).

Another problem that I have is that I don't know how can I get HID descriptor. I know it's possible by calling **GetDescriptor** method, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent conflict with Windows reading from the mouse, you should disable the associated mouse instance in Device Manager.

If you want shared access to mouse data, use a [low-level mouse hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx), not libusb.  If you really want it in USB HID message format, you can use a filter driver to get a copy of every request and response Windows gets from the device.